# How to get top parent id from a child id using php?

Tags: php

I am an amateur in PHP. I tried a lot of suggestions from here but I didn't get the result I need. I want to get the top parent id of a child. ex. For id=10 top parent is 8. This is the array I get from the database. Thanks in advance.

```
$events = mysqli_query($dbtmx,"SELECT * FROM tmetrix_events WHERE status='1'");
while($re=mysqli_fetch_assoc($events)){
  $array[] = array('id'=>$re['id'],'parent_id'=>$re['parent_id']);
}
```

And the array I am receiving is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent_id] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent_id] => 8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [parent_id] => 9
        )

)
```

Now I want to find the top parent or root parent id of the child.

I tried Steverst1 and AymDev's code. But I am getting the result.

Comment: Please show us your best attempt (code), you might be closer to a solution than you think. Please read [ask] and take the [tour], these will help you better understand how to ask a question.

Comment: Hello, you say 'For id=10 top parent is 8.' Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @St3an Parent of 10 is 9, parent of 9 is 8, 8 has no parent. Therefore, 8 is the "top parent" of 10.

Comment: You say "8 has no parent"... are you sure ?

Comment: @St3an I would assume that `0` means no parent. I haven't encountered any systems using a zero as an actual id.

Comment: @berend Thanks for your suggestion. I will read How to Ask and take the tour.

Comment: @St3an El_Vanja is right. id-8 has no parent, hence the parent_id is 0.
8->9->10. 10 is the child of 9 and 9 is the child of 8. Sorry for replying late.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function which will run through all parents until it finds `0` which I assume means there is no parent:

```php
function get_top_parent(int $id, array $list): ?array
{
    // Find current item
    $key = array_search($id, array_column($list, 'id'));
    $item = $list[$key] ?? null;
    
    // Check if item has parent
    if (null !== $item && $item['parent_id'] !== 0) {
        // recursive call
        return get_top_parent($item['parent_id'], $list);
    }
    
    // No parent (or no item)
    return $item;
}
```

> Tested on **3v4l.org**: https://3v4l.org/PPm3K

Comment: @AmyDev I tried your code. But I am not getting the result. I updated the question. Please let me know the mistake.

Comment: Sorry but the code I provided gives exactly what you asked for. If you check the 3v4l.org link I pass `10` in parameter to the function and it returns the array of the id `8`. You updated your question but without additional information. How are you *"not getting the result"* ?

Comment: Yes when I use your full code from 3v4l.org I get the result. But when I use with the array generated from sql. I am not getting the result. The exact array from sql query
```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 5 [parent_id] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 6 [parent_id] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 7 [parent_id] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 8 [parent_id] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 9 [parent_id] => 8 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 10 [parent_id] => 9 ) )
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the array generated?

Comment: This array is exactly the same I used to provide my answer, therefore it works as shown in the link. You must be using it wrong.

Comment: I used your code like this. Am I using it right? https://3v4l.org/7VAWK

Comment: Yes it should return the array for the `8` id. Did you encounter any issue with this code ? Just to add, you should define`$array = [];` before your `while` loop, just in case your SQL query does not return any result.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption that 0 in `parent_id` means that it is the parent we are looking for. So get the id of it.

```php
$child_id = 10;
$parent = 0;
while ($child_id != 0) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $inner_arr) {
        $id = $inner_arr['id'];
        $parent_id = $inner_arr['parent_id'];
        if($id === $child_id){
            $child_id = $parent_id;
            $parent = $id;
        }
    }
}
echo $parent; // 8
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/iiDtN)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not getting the result. I updated my question.